# Will this error "findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode." fail when deploying my react project?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

When I'm going to deploy my react project even with this error "findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode." will it fail during deployment? This error was due to Material-UI's persistent drawer, dialog, and muidatatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's a harmless error because Material-UI uses a deprecated method somewhere that triggers in `StrictMode`. You won't see that error in production since `StrictMode` is only available in development. It's been going for a while and they plan to fix it in version 5, so just wait. See this issue [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394).